# create a class list dont allow duplicated entries

Tags: python

i'm trying to create a class does not allow duplicate entryies

```
class QSet(list):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        super(QSet, self).__init__(args[0])
        self=list(set(self))
```

and when try to test the class duplicated entries not removed

```
d=["a","b","a","z","a"]
z=QList(d)       

print d  
print z
```

any suggestion to solve this 
Thanks

Comment: how bout `list.__init__(self,list(set(self)))`

Comment: if you are going to allow insertion perhaps what you want is a set or an ordereddict

Comment: When you say "does not allow" - it's not disallowing them, it's silently just not having them.... And then what if I change an index to an existing value - what then? Plus, if I provide a sequence sequence to something like this, I'm going to have a bit of a surprise if it doesn't maintain the order I gave it... Not sure you've thought through how practical this actually is... (You might just be after an ordered set implementation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reassigning `self` doesn't actually change the object (you're just rebinding the identifier `self` to a new object). You could change the line to:

```
    self[:] = list(set(self))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do what you want with a small change to your code:

```
class QSet(list):
    def __init__(self, a):
        super(QSet, self).__init__(list(set(a)))
```

I changed how you use the constructor args, because its odd to accept arbitrary arguments, but then insist there be at least one, and ignore all the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You know that [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) is exactly the class you are building, right?

```
>>> s = set([1,2,3,3,3])
>>> s.add(4)
>>> s
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> s.add(4)
>>> s
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already a class in Python for that. It is called set

```
d=["a","b","a","z","a"]
z=set(d)       

print d  
print z
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: yes work but i'd like to build class do QSet tasks which is missed in pyqt4